# Wrong Visual Studio assembly output?

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

I wrote this classic function : (in 32-bit mode)

```
void ex(size_t a, size_t b)
{
    size_t c;
    c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

I call it inside the main as follows :

```
size_t a = 4;
size_t b = 5;
ex(a,b);
```

What I was expecting from the assembly code generated when entering the function is something like this :

1-Push the values of b and a in the stack : (which was done)

```
mov         eax,dword ptr [b]
push        eax
mov         ecx,dword ptr [a]
push        ecx
```

2-Use the values of a and b in the stack :

```
push        ebp
mov         ebp, esp
sub         esp, 4
    c = a;
mov         eax, dword ptr [ebp+8]
mov         dword ptr [ebp-4], eax
```

and so on for the other variables.

However, this is what I find when debugging :

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp,esp  
sub         esp,0CCh  // normal since it's in debug with ZI option
push        ebx  
push        esi  
push        edi  
lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
mov         ecx,33h  
mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    size_t c;
    c = a;
mov         eax,dword ptr [a]  
mov         dword ptr [c],eax
```

Why is it using the variable a directly instead of calling the value stored in the stack? I don't understand...

Comment: integers stored in the stack cannot be called. Only functions are called. You need to use some other verb.

Comment: Your function is nonsensical, so you could really expect anything nonsensical to happen.  You are manipulating some local variables and then returning without a return value and without any side effect.  I would bet that in a non-debug build your function would be compiled to nothing.

Comment: I'm surprised that there is any code generated since the funciton does not do anything.

Comment: The compiler is simply using `a` as an alias of `ebp+8` and `c` as an alias of `ebp-4`.  If the generated assembly code actually compiles, then these aliases are defined somewhere.  If not, then `a` and `c` are indicative only.

Comment: @Mike Nakis Actually this was an example from a course I took, an example that shows the difference between passing arguments by value and by address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debugger doesn't show the instruction using `ebp` to access `a`. The same syntax is permitted when you write inline assembly.  Otherwise the reason that `dword ptr` still appears.

It is easy to get it your preferred way, right click > untick "Show Symbol Names".

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using the assembly output option (right click on file name, properties, ...), I get what you expect from debug assembly output. This could depend on which version of VS you use. For this example, I used VS2005. I have VS2015 on a different system, but didn't try it yet.

```
_c$ = -8                                ; size = 4
_a$ = 8                                 ; size = 4
_b$ = 12                                ; size = 4
_ex     PROC                            ; COMDAT
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 204                ; 000000ccH
        push    ebx
        push    esi
        push    edi
        lea     edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-204]
        mov     ecx, 51                 ; 00000033H
        mov     eax, -858993460         ; ccccccccH
        rep stosd                       ;fill with 0cccccccch
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR _c$[ebp], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _b$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR _a$[ebp], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _c$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR _b$[ebp], eax
        pop     edi
        pop     esi
        pop     ebx
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
_ex     ENDP
```

Note this doesn't work, you need to use pointers for the swap to work.

```
void ex(size_t *pa, size_t *pb)
{
    size_t c;
      c = *pa;
    *pa = *pb;
    *pb = c;
}
```

which gets translated into:

```
_c$ = -8                                ; size = 4
_pa$ = 8                                ; size = 4
_pb$ = 12                               ; size = 4
_ex     PROC                            ; COMDAT
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 204                ; 000000ccH
        push    ebx
        push    esi
        push    edi
        lea     edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-204]
        mov     ecx, 51                 ; 00000033H
        mov     eax, -858993460         ; ccccccccH
        rep stosd
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _pa$[ebp]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [eax]
        mov     DWORD PTR _c$[ebp], ecx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _pa$[ebp]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _pb$[ebp]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [ecx]
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], edx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _pb$[ebp]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _c$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], ecx
        pop     edi
        pop     esi
        pop     ebx
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
_ex     ENDP
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. As Hans Passant said in his answer, it's because I had the option "Show Symbol Names" ticked, which lead Visual Studio to replace EBP+8 with the symbol a.